# Codeigniter missing argument 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm learning to make a simple login through codeigniter, then I got an error like 
`Missing argument 1 for C_login::login()` when I press the "login" button on my views without entering the username and password field.

these are my controller, my IDE (netbeanPHP+CI framework) shows no error

```
<?php
class C_login extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_login'); 
}

function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','trim|Username','required|exact_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','trim|Password','required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]|xss_clean|callback_login');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'sukses validasi';
    }

}

function login($password)
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $jabatan = $this->input->post('jabatan');

    $value = $this->m_login->cekpass($username,$password,$jabatan);

    if($value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}


}
 ?>
```

and here is the model, i think my model is not showing any error

```
<?php
class M_login extends CI_Model{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function login ($username, $password, $jabatan)
{
   $this->db->where('username',$username);
   $this->db->where('password',$password);
   $this->db->where('jabatan',$jabatan);

   $value = $this->db->get('ms_user');

   if($value->num_rows()>0)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }


}
}?>
```

Comment: remove the `$password` parameter from the login function, or give it a default value. `function login($password = null)`

Comment: @VladBalmos it shows another error `call to undefined method M_Login :: cekpass() in controller/c_login line 35

Comment: You named the function `login` in the model not `cekpass`.

Comment: where is `cekpass()` defined? I don't see it in your model

Comment: oh you're right @KemalFadillah i was following some of tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the formal parameter `$password` from the `login` method of the `C_login` controller. Obviously, you're not gonna pass the password via the URL, right?

As for the second error regarding the undefined method in the model, it's because you're calling the method you want with the wrong name. You named it `login` in the model, yet you're calling for `cekpass` in the controller. Either rename the method definition, or change what you're calling to `login` instead.

Comment: so if there's a method named `getDB()` in dbModel, we must use function `getdb()` in controller to access `getdb()` in dbModel  ?

Comment: @Cignitor no, just make sure the name of the method you're calling is the right one.